# Error con la gema devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

Tengo un proyecto nuevo en el cual le instale la gema devise para la autenticación de usuarios, cuando fui a probarla me dio un error:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Fichero de rutas:

```rb
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  devise_for :users
  root 'main#home'
end
```

modelo usuario:

```rb
class User < ApplicationRecord
  before_create :user_default

  enum rol: [:"Superadmin", :"Administrator", :"user"]
  
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :validatable

  private
    def user_default
      self.rol = :"user"
    end
end
```

Para probar la autenticación cree una vista de prueba llamada main.
Su controlador:

```rb
class MainController < ApplicationController
  before_action :authenticate_user!
  def home
  end
end
```

su vista:

```rb
<h1>Main#home</h1>
<p>Find me in app/views/main/home.html.erb</p>
```

En la carpeta de los controladores no encuentro el controlador registrations_controller.rb ni tampoco se creo las vistas en la carpeta.

Aun con todo puedo crear usuario y loguearme, pese al error. Creo que este se produce cuando hace la redirección a la vista creada.

La versión de ruby que utilizo es la 3.1.3 y la de rails es la 7.0.4

Gracias por la ayuda.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Parece ser un error común [con Turbo y Devise 4.8.1](https://github.com/heartcombo/devise/issues/5439).
En tu archivo `config/initializers/devise.rb` agrega:

```
config.navigational_formats = ['*/*', :html, :turbo_stream]
```